# Building a custom animation timeline in Winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, timeline

I'm building a personal animation tool in Winforms and having trouble conceptualizing which toolbox component would be best to create an animation timeline from much like the timeline within Maya.

The criteria is a single layer (unlike Flash) that when played, a simple line over the layer will scroll across from left->right based on the duration settings (maximum of 60 fps).

What I'm looking for is advice on the best component with the toolbox to base the timeline off of.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks for the comment, but it didn't answer my question...

Comment: no, a `comment` is not intended to `answer` a question, just to comment on it. Otherwise it wouldn't be a `comment`, it would be an `answer`. Good luck trying to hack anything useful out of winforms.

Comment: Do you want to create a control at the top/bottom of your form that draws a partial line from left to right (length depending on time passed vs time allowed) that updates at enough speed to seem fluid. Or, do you want to draw a vertical line over the entire of your Form (or Control in the Form) that moves across the Form/Control in the same manner?